# Get EntCannotSeeExistenceException trying to post to "/me/feed" with a test user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Developing a WP7 app, and I'm trying to post something to the user's feed.  We have all this working on iPhone already, and we have a test account created already.  With the iPhone it's able to post to our test user's page.

I'm trying to use the Facebook C# sdk to do the same thing, using the same account.  I can successfully login to the test user's account and obtain the AccessToken.  When I login, the extended permissions I request from the user are "read_stream", "publish_stream", "publish_checkins".

When I try to do something like this:

```
var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "message", "Howdy!" }
};

client.PostAsync("/me/feed", parameters);
```

Then it fails, and observing client.PostCompleted I see the error is:

> (EntCannotSeeExistenceException) The entity (class EntPlatformTestUser)
>   backed by id 1234 cannot be seen by the current viewer 1234 (EntID: 1234)

I found a blog post[1] where someone was running into this exception, and he solved it by switching out of sandbox mode.  But we're already not in sandbox mode.  Plus, as I described above, everything is working just fine using the iPhone SDK.  This leads me to think that I'm just doing something wrong with the C# SDK.

[1]. http://test.ical.ly/2011/03/10/facebook-graphapi-uncaught-entcannotseeexistenceexception-the-entity-class-entapplication-backed-by-id-12345-cannot-be-seen-by-the-current-viewer-12345-entid-12345/

Comment: After doing some more poking around I've learned that: 1/ The iPhone SDK is not using the Graph API, it's just using iframes in web browser controls, and 2/ when I do this with a non-test user, it works just fine.  That makes me wonder wtf is the point of test users if they can't access any of the Graph API. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem just now:

- posting does **not work with old test account** that was made through old website procedure.
- posting **works ok with real** account

**Solution**:
 create new test user through new graph API and it should work. At least it worked for me.